# Laravel : JWT token expired

Tags: laravel, jwt, laravel-5.5

I am using the [`tymondesigns/jwt-auth`](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) package for my app, but it is show `token expired` message after some time.
I already set `'ttl' => null` and also remove `exp` but it did not work.

Here is my `config/jwt.php`

```
<?php

/*
* This file is part of jwt-auth.
*
* (c) Sean Tymon <tymon148@gmail.com>
*
* For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
* file that was distributed with this source code.
*/

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| JWT Authentication Secret
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Don't forget to set this in your .env file, as it will be used to sign
| your tokens. A helper command is provided for this:
| `php artisan jwt:secret`
|
| Note: This will be used for Symmetric algorithms only (HMAC),
| since RSA and ECDSA use a private/public key combo (See below).
|
*/
// 'secret' => 'my-dummy-jwt-token',
'secret' => 'key',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| JWT Authentication Keys
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The algorithm you are using, will determine whether your tokens are
| signed with a random string (defined in `JWT_SECRET`) or using the
| following public & private keys.
|
| Symmetric Algorithms:
| HS256, HS384 & HS512 will use `JWT_SECRET`.
|
| Asymmetric Algorithms:
| RS256, RS384 & RS512 / ES256, ES384 & ES512 will use the keys below.
|
*/

'keys' => [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Public Key
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | A path or resource to your public key.
    |
    | E.g. 'file://path/to/public/key'
    |
    */

    'public' => env('JWT_PUBLIC_KEY'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Private Key
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | A path or resource to your private key.
    |
    | E.g. 'file://path/to/private/key'
    |
    */

    'private' => env('JWT_PRIVATE_KEY'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Passphrase
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The passphrase for your private key. Can be null if none set.
    |
    */

    'passphrase' => env('JWT_PASSPHRASE'),

],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| JWT time to live
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Specify the length of time (in minutes) that the token will be valid for.
| Defaults to 1 hour.
|
| You can also set this to null, to yield a never expiring token.
| Some people may want this behaviour for e.g. a mobile app.
| This is not particularly recommended, so make sure you have appropriate
| systems in place to revoke the token if necessary.
|
*/

//'ttl' => env('JWT_TTL', 60),
 'ttl' => null,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Refresh time to live
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Specify the length of time (in minutes) that the token can be refreshed
| within. I.E. The user can refresh their token within a 2 week window of
| the original token being created until they must re-authenticate.
| Defaults to 2 weeks.
|
| You can also set this to null, to yield an infinite refresh time.
| Some may want this instead of never expiring tokens for e.g. a mobile app.
| This is not particularly recommended, so make sure you have appropriate
| systems in place to revoke the token if necessary.
|
*/

'refresh_ttl' => env('JWT_REFRESH_TTL', 20160),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| JWT hashing algorithm
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Specify the hashing algorithm that will be used to sign the token.
|
| See here: https://github.com/namshi/jose/tree/master/src/Namshi/JOSE/Signer/OpenSSL
| for possible values.
|
*/

'algo' => env('JWT_ALGO', 'HS256'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Required Claims
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Specify the required claims that must exist in any token.
| A TokenInvalidException will be thrown if any of these claims are not
| present in the payload.
|
*/

'required_claims' => [
    'iss',
    'iat',
   'nbf',
    'sub',
    'jti',
],
 //'exp', remove token expire time

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Persistent Claims
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Specify the claim keys to be persisted when refreshing a token.
| `sub` and `iat` will automatically be persisted, in
| addition to the these claims.
|
| Note: If a claim does not exist then it will be ignored.
|
*/

'persistent_claims' => [
    // 'foo',
    // 'bar',
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Blacklist Enabled
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| In order to invalidate tokens, you must have the blacklist enabled.
| If you do not want or need this functionality, then set this to false.
|
*/

'blacklist_enabled' => env('JWT_BLACKLIST_ENABLED', true),

/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Blacklist Grace Period
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When multiple concurrent requests are made with the same JWT,
| it is possible that some of them fail, due to token regeneration
| on every request.
|
| Set grace period in seconds to prevent parallel request failure.
|
*/

'blacklist_grace_period' => env('JWT_BLACKLIST_GRACE_PERIOD', 0),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Specify the various providers used throughout the package.
|
*/

'providers' => [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | JWT Provider
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Specify the provider that is used to create and decode the tokens.
    |
    */

    'jwt' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWT\Namshi::class,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Provider
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Specify the provider that is used to authenticate users.
    |
    */

    'auth' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\Auth\Illuminate::class,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Storage Provider
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Specify the provider that is used to store tokens in the blacklist.
    |
    */

    'storage' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\Storage\Illuminate::class,

],

 ];
```

Is there any other setting for remove expiry time ?

Comment: Could you share a jwt generated by your application for debug purposes? do delete the signature part of it for security purposes.

Comment: Something similar to the `encoded` side of the [jwt.io demo site](https://jwt.io/), i'd like to double check the exact value of the `exp` claim.

Comment: I am assuming either in a session, header or cookie

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170374/discussion-between-quezler-and-javed).

Comment: let's move to the chat channel before this comment chain gets out of hand :)

Comment: Please join me in this [stackoverflow chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170374/discussion-between-quezler-and-javed)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this

```
'ttl' => env('JWT_TTL', 1440)
```

Changing the default 60 to 1440 will make the token last for a day, this work for me, hope it helps you

Comment: This worked for me, I added the environment variable and it worked.

Comment: Do I have to change JWT_TTL and JWT_TTL_REFRESH together? Because I have noticed that JWT_TTL_REFRESH is 2 times of JWT_TTL.

I have hosted my backend with Azure. I was wondering if I have to restart the server or clear cache once this code is deployed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this and use dynamic timing for expiration of your token

```
 auth()->attempt($credentials, ['exp' => Carbon::now()->addYears(2)->timestamp])
```

or this

```
auth()->attempt($credentials, ['exp' => Carbon::now()->addMonths(2)->timestamp])
```

Use Carbon for your token expiry time

Answer (score 0):

If like that, i would like to pass if token is expired...
You can place this code in middleware..

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    $token =  JWTAuth::getToken();
    try {
        $user = JWTAuth::authenticate($token);
    } catch (\Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException $e) {
        return $next($request);
    } catch (\Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException $e) {
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 500,
            'message' => 'Token Invalid',
        ], 500);
    } catch (\Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException $e) {
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 500,
            'message' => $e->getMessage(),
        ], 500);
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

and dont forget to include JWTAuth... in your top of code...

```
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth;
```

Comment: I set response like that so that it can used for ajax of axios